# Javascript animation of a svg

Tags: javascript, svg

i am trying to animate the radius of the circle #mask-hole-2 with javascript. so that it animates the radius from 0 to 145px. but i dont  know how to do this in a common way. i cant use css cause there seems to be another specification used on firefox for animating masks with css. any help is appreciated.

```
 <svg width="400" height="300">
  <defs>
   <mask id="hole">
     <circle id="mask-hole-1" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="165" fill="white" />
    <rect id="mask-hole-3" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
    <circle id="mask-hole-2" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="145" />
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <image width="400" height="300"
       xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/"
       mask="url(#hole)"/>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Try this example code I just wrote that will make the hole shrink away. This should give you an idea of what you can do for other effects within your svg.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ani()
{
$("#mask-hole-2").animate({
r: 0
}, 2000)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="400" height="300">
  <defs>
   <mask id="hole">
     <circle id="mask-hole-1" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="165" fill="white" />
    <rect id="mask-hole-3" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
    <circle id="mask-hole-2" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="145" />
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <image width="400" height="300"
       xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/"
       mask="url(#hole)"/>
 </svg>
 <input type="button" value="animate" onclick="ani()" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Hopefully that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```js
var circle = $("#mask-hole-2");
var bigger = false;

setInterval(function(){ 
  
  if(bigger == true)
  {
    circle.attr("r", Number(circle.attr("r"))+1);
  }
  else
  {
    circle.attr("r", Number(circle.attr("r"))-1);
  }
  
  if(Number(circle.attr("r")) >= 145)
  {
    bigger = false;
  }
  
    if(Number(circle.attr("r")) <= 1)
  {
    bigger = true;
  }


 }, 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="300">
  <defs>
   <mask id="hole">
     <circle id="mask-hole-1" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="165" fill="white" />
    <rect id="mask-hole-3" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
    <circle id="mask-hole-2" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="145" />
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <image width="400" height="300"
       xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/"
       mask="url(#hole)"/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: thx so far. thats close to what i want reach. i want #mask-hole-1 to change it s radius within 2 seconds from 0 to 175. after 2s #mask-hole-2 should change its radius from 0 to 175 also. could you please adjust the snippet?

Comment: You just need to do the same action, you can do it with your hands, please mark the answer as correct ^^